# Zappy SSIS inserts / in front of ,

Tags: csv, ssis

We have this software for SSIS and are trying to export data to a CSV file. The data includes a , in some instances for "Vendor Name". The export inserts a / in front of the , for some reason.

So for example `ABC, INC` shows up as `ABC\, INC` after the export.

Is there a solution to this so that \ is not inserted?

Thank you.

Raj

Comment: *So for example ABC, INC shows up as ABC, INC after the export.* - is that what you expect though, I don't see a "/".

Comment: It seems that this website removed the / in the name as well but it shows up with a / before the ,

Comment: Use the editor tools to format as code and it will show correctly.

Comment: The software is probably trying to escape the in-field comma.  If you have options to put quotes "..." around individual fields in your CSV output and your receiving application can work with quoted fields in CSV files, this might be a way to proceed

Comment: Stu, How do I format as code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the software that you're using, but a slash is often used as an escape character to indicate, in this case, that the comma is part of the text in the column and not a column delimiter. The import function for the software probably leverages that.

Assuming that the file recipient is not using that same software package, I'd look around in the settings/configs for the software to see if there's a way to force it to use a more standard notation. For instance, surrounding the exported text columns in double quotes causes most import specs to treat internal commas as normal text rather than delimters.

You'll be looking for something like the `Text Qualifier` setting in the stock SSIS Flat File Connection Manager.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. I will try to see if there is a work around or whether it's a software bug